# Kendo MobileListView - can't get it to populate on remote source

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I've tried to populate both the kendoMobileListView and the kendoListView with a remote source, but I just can't get it to populate with data.

The ItemBound event does not seem to fire.

If I use a local datasource then it works.

HTML:

```
  <div data-role="view" data-use-native-scrolling="true" data-layout="default" data-title="Mobile-layout">  
    <div id="items-listview"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Main Layout -->
  <div data-role="layout" data-id="default">
    <header data-role="header">
      <div data-role="navbar"><span data-role="view-title"></span></div>
    </header>
    <!-- View Content -->
    <div data-role="footer">
      <div data-role="tabstrip">
        Footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    kendoApp = new kendo.mobile.Application($(document.body));

    var myDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport:{
            read: {
                url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers",
                dataType: "odata"
            }
        }
    });
    /*
    $("#items-listview").kendoMobileListView({     
            dataSource: {
              data: [
                { name: "Test 1" },
              { name: "Test 2" }
              ]
           },
      template: "<div>Blalbalblaa</div>"
    });

    */

        $("#items-listview").kendoMobileListView({     
            dataSource: myDataSource,
      template: "<div>blalbalal</div>"
    });    

});
```

Please see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasonBr81/3zjtcwr0/38/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the datatype to "jsonp" and changed url to http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products, which returns a json object.

It then works!